# Copy files on Mac by using regular expression

Tags: macos

I have close to hundreds of `.fastq` files in different subfolders under a shared drive along with many big files such as `.bam` files. I want to copy only the `.fastq` files to another location in a same folder to perform an analysis. How can I do it on a Mac? I tried:

```
find -E . -iregex '.*/*\.fastq'
```

which showed all the files along with the relative path, but I don't need the path. And I cannot figure out a pipeline to copy them to another location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use regexes if you're just looking for files with a particular extension.

```
find . -name '*.fastq' -exec mv {} /new/dir/ \;
```